# How do I efficiently bind a DropdownListFor to a nested class when looping over a collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am struggling getting a DropDownListFor to work. The system is a timesheet system, and the relevant classes are `Week`:

```
public class Week
{
    public int WeekId { get; set; }
    public List<TimeEntry> TimeEntries { get; set; }
    public Week()
    {
        TimeEntries = new List<TimeEntry>();
    }
}
```

Each `Week` contains a list of `TimeEntries`:

```
public class TimeEntry
{
    public int TimeEntryID { get; set; }
    public double MonHours { get; set; }
    public double TueHours { get; set; }
    public double WedHours { get; set; }
    public double ThuHours { get; set; }
    public double FriHours { get; set; }

    public int BillingStatusID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BillingStatusID")]
    public virtual BillingStatus BillingStatus { get; set; }
}
```

And each `TimeEntry` has a `BillingStatus` (e.g. Paid, Pending, Invoiced):

```
public class BillingStatus
{
    public int BillingStatusID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }  
}
```

The way that data is entered is from the WeekController. This has a series of rows, one for each entry in the database. Additional rows can be added too, so there is dual functionality for Edit/Create of TimeEntries via the WeekController:

[image]

I am having trouble getting the DropDownLists for BillingStatus to work, however. I think this is because I am rendering the rows by means of a loop. It is made more complex however, by the fact that the BillingStatus is not stored in the `Week` class, but in the `TimeEntry` class. (So kind of "one level down" from the Controller I am using.

If I hard code the list in the DropDownListFor control it works:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.TimeEntries.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="index" style="display:none">@Model.TimeEntries[i].TimeEntryID</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.TimeEntries[i].ClientID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ClientID, "Select...", new { style = "width:100%" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.TimeEntries[i].TaskTypeID, (SelectList)ViewBag.TaskTypeID, "Select...", new { style = "width:100%" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.TimeEntries[i].MonHours, new { style = "width:100%", @class = "hours mon" })</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.TimeEntries[i].TueHours, new { style = "width:100%", @class = "hours tue" })</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.TimeEntries[i].WedHours, new { style = "width:100%", @class = "hours wed" })</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.TimeEntries[i].ThuHours, new { style = "width:100%", @class = "hours thu" })</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.TimeEntries[i].FriHours, new { style = "width:100%", @class = "hours fri" })</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">@Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.TimeEntries[i].Comment)</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.TimeEntries[i].BillingStatusID,
                 new SelectList(new List<Object>{
                                    new { BillingStatusID = 0 , Name = "Pending"  },
                                    new { BillingStatusID = 1 , Name = "Invoiced"  },
                                    new { BillingStatusID = 2 , Name = "Paid"  },
                 }, "BillingStatusID", "Name", Model.TimeEntries[i].BillingStatusID))
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

However, if I try and populate it from the database it fails. I have tried the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.BillingStatusID, new SelectList(Model.TimeEntries[0].BillingStatuses, "BillingStatusId", "Name", "Select..."))
```

and have also tried using a ViewBag in the WeekController:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.TimeEntries[i].BillingStatusID,
                         new SelectList(ViewBag.BSID,
                        "BillingStatusID", "Name", Model.TimeEntries[i].BillingStatusID))
```

but neither approach works. I also want to make sure I am not hitting the database every time a row is rendered, as this seems really inefficient.

I guess what I want to be able to do is to get this:

```
new List<Object>{
    new { BillingStatusID = 0 , Name = "Pending"  },
    new { BillingStatusID = 1 , Name = "Invoiced"  },
    new { BillingStatusID = 2 , Name = "Paid"  },
    }
```

in one hit when the page is loaded, and then use the SelectList to wrap around it. However, I don't know where I should get it from. Should I return it from the Controller?

I'm pretty new to MVC, so only just getting my head round concepts like ViewModels, ViewBags and EditorFor - so please asssume I know nothing when answering!!

Comment: You have not shown how you have attempted to populate it (either `BillingStatuses` or `ViewBag.BSID` - and your model does not even show a property named `BillingStatuses`). In any case, its your `Week` class that should contain a property `IEnumerable<BillingStatus>` so that its only populated once.

Comment: Cool - thanks @StephenMuecke. That's partly what I was stuck on - where it should go. (Seems there is a bit of "re-thinking" in terms of classes with MVC.